# How to scroll an element you are not focused in using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How does sites like [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com) and 9gag's [fast version](http://9gag.com/fast#4122318) do this:

On Pinterest if you click on any image and get the modal you will notice that scrolling anywhere on the page causes the modal to scroll and not the main document.

On 9gag if you scroll anywhere except the comment section, it's the main content area on the left that scrolls.

In either case, you don't have to be focused on the area you would like to scroll. Just scrolling anywhere even if your mouse isn't inside the area you want to scroll, causes that area to be scrolled.

How do they achieve this? For example how can one disable scrolling on the main document and cause some div on the page to scroll in it's place?

Comment: Examples are always useful, and are encouraged, however please try to refrain from giving 9gag any publicity; it's a scumbag site in all senses of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Pinterest, when a modal opens up, a class of "noscroll" is added to the `<body/>`:

```
.noscroll {overflow: hidden !important;}
```

This prevents the `body` from scrolling. The modal itself has an id of "zoomscroll" which contains the following:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

So while the `body` is frozen, the overflow of `#zoomscroll` can be scrolled.

Have a look at the demo here: http://jsbin.com/ucacon/2/edit — Click on any paragraph to freeze the body, and enable scrolling on the paragraph itself.

Comment: +1 Exactly. That is a neat effect and so freaking simple. Added the jQuery code for the OP.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson Ok so if the body has overflow: hidden then the scroll bar should completely disappear but how is it still there on the right rail? Also with the modal having overflow-y: scroll, shouldn't scroll bars appear inside the modal and only scroll if your mouse inside the modal area rather than anywhere on the page?

Comment: @JakeRow123 You're seeing the scrollbar from the `#zoomscroll` container.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual CSS they have on their modal.

```
#zoomScroll {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    overflow-x: auto;
    -y: scroll;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

That plus the body class noscroll makes it work.

```
.noscroll {overflow: hidden !important;}
```